# Extra column in webRTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I'm practicing some code by making a webRTC app which also recognizes users within the call. Almost everything is working, except when someone joins in the call, there is always an extra div being created. What I was planning to do was create a single div and add the video in only once, below is the code :

```
const socket = io('/')
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid');
const vidHeight = 500 
const vidWidth = 500 
const checkerBoxHeight = 53

//Flags used to check workers gone or not and for how long
var absentTime = 0;
var present = true;
var time=0;

//Load facial recognition models 
Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
]).then(console.log("Models Loaded!"));

    const myPeer = new Peer(undefined,{
        host : '/',
        port : '3001'
    })

    
/**************************************************/
//Initial Self Video Creation Starts Here
/*************************************************/
   //Create Video

const myVideo = document.createElement('video');
myVideo.setAttribute("id","myVideo");
myVideo.setAttribute("class","vidNum");

myVideo.style.height = vidHeight - checkerBoxHeight + 'px'
myVideo.style.width = vidWidth + 'px'
myVideo.muted = true
   

/**************************************************/
//Initial Self Video Creation Ends Here
/*************************************************/

/**************************************************/
//Peers and Streaming begins here
/*************************************************/
                
        const peers = {}
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video : true,
            audio : true,
        }).then(stream =>{

        //add own video to the stream
        addVideoStream(myVideo,stream)
    
        //When someone calls Answer and create new video element WITH set height and width for facial recognition canvas(new)
        //answer their call then send them our stream 
        myPeer.on('call', call =>{
        call.answer(stream);
        const video = document.createElement('video')  
        video.style.height = vidHeight - checkerBoxHeight + 'px'
        video.style.width = vidWidth + 'px'        
       
        //On call, add new video stream to newly created video 
            call.on('stream', userVideoStream =>{
                   addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
            })
        })

        //When user is connected, connect them 
        //then add them in to own screen 
        socket.on('user-connected', userId =>{

            setTimeout(connectToNewUser,500,userId,stream)
            console.log(userId + ' Joined the call!');
          // connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
        })

        socket.on('user-disconnected', userId =>{
            console.log(userId + ' Left the call!');
            if(peers[userId])  peers[userId].close()
        })
        
    })

    myPeer.on('open', id =>{
        socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id)
    })

   
/**************************************************/
//Peers and Streaming ends here
/*************************************************/
   

/*************************************************************/
//FUNCTIONS BEGIN HERE
/************************************************************/

 //Connect to new user function
function connectToNewUser(userId,stream){

        const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream)
        //to show existing users 
        const video = document.createElement('video')
        video.style.height = vidHeight - checkerBoxHeight + 'px'
        video.style.width = vidWidth + 'px'

        call.on('stream', userVideoStream =>{
           addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
         })
        
        call.on('close', ()=>{
            video.parentElement.remove()
        })
    
        peers[userId] = call

    }


function createBox(){
    
}

//Add video stream function
function addVideoStream(video,stream){
   
      
    
    video.srcObject = stream
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () =>{
        video.play()
           
    })

    //ADD VIDEO BOX TO VIDEO GRID 
    const videoBox = document.createElement("div");
    videoBox.setAttribute("class",'videoBox');
    videoGrid.append(videoBox);

    //THEN, ADD CHECKER BOX 
    const checkerBox = document.createElement("div");
    checkerBox.style.width = vidWidth + 'px'
    checkerBox.style.height = checkerBoxHeight - 6 + 'px'
    videoBox.append(checkerBox);
    checkerBox.setAttribute("id","checkerBox");
    
     
    videoBox.append(video)
  //detectFace(video,videoBox);
  //checkIfPresent();
}



//Facial Detection
function detectFace(faceCam,vidBox){

        faceCam.addEventListener('play', () =>{
         
        const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(faceCam)
        vidBox.append(canvas);

        setInterval(async()=>{
          
            //finding detections
            const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(faceCam,
              new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks()

              const displaySize = { 
                  width: vidWidth ,
                   height: vidHeight - checkerBoxHeight
                }

              faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas,displaySize)

              const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections,displaySize)
              //clear
            canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0,0, canvas.width,canvas.height)
          

              faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
              faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas,resizedDetections)
               
              //Create green or red box depending on if the person is present 
              var checkerBox = document.getElementById("checkerBox");
              
                if(detections.length>=1){
                present = true;
                 absentTime = 0;
                 checkerBoxTrue(checkerBox)
                    }else{
                        present = false;
                        absentTime++;         
                        checkerBoxFalse(checkerBox)
                    }


            }, 100)
        })
    }


function checkIfPresent(){

   setInterval(function(){
    if(present == false){
        console.log("Worker is not present for : " + Math.ceil(absentTime/10) + " seconds");
    }
   
   },1000)

}

function checkerBoxTrue(checkerBox){
    checkerBox.style.backgroundColor="green";
    checkerBox.innerHTML = "<h1 class='workerStatus'>Worker is Present</h1>";
}

function checkerBoxFalse(checkerBox){
    checkerBox.style.backgroundColor="red";
    checkerBox.innerHTML = "<h1 class='workerStatus'>Worker is NOT Present</h1>";
}
```

HTML Is just a basic script with 2 divs

```
<body>
    <div class = "grid-container">
        <div id="video-grid"> </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't built exactly what you're trying to build before, when I've built video apps on top of third-party WebRTC libraries like [Daily](https://www.daily.co/) (full disclosure, I work there), I've seen an extra video "tile" div show up when I forget to loop over everyone *but* the local camera stream. Are you accounting for that already?

For example, here's the `getTiles` function in a [React video chat app](https://github.com/daily-demos/call-object-react/blob/main/src/components/Call/Call.js):

```js
function getTiles() {
    let largeTiles = [];
    let smallTiles = [];
    Object.entries(callState.callItems).forEach(([id, callItem]) => {
      const isLarge =
        isScreenShare(id) ||
        (!isLocal(id) && !containsScreenShare(callState.callItems));
      const tile = (
        <Tile
          key={id}
          videoTrackState={callItem.videoTrackState}
          audioTrackState={callItem.audioTrackState}
          isLocalPerson={isLocal(id)}
          isLarge={isLarge}
          disableCornerMessage={isScreenShare(id)}
          onClick={
            isLocal(id)
              ? null
              : () => {
                  sendHello(id);
                }
          }
        />
      );
      if (isLarge) {
        largeTiles.push(tile);
      } else {
        smallTiles.push(tile);
      }
    });
    return [largeTiles, smallTiles];
  }
```

Where `isLocal` is imported from separate call state. I hope that could help somewhat, and good luck!